# No more windows grouping on Lubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)

Tags: lubuntu

I've recently installed Lubuntu 23.04 over 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) and the new version doens't have the feature of grouping opened windows of the same software (e.g. Firefox Browser). So my panel gets very messy since I usually open more than 4 programs, 4 windows each (total 16 tabs on the panel). See the print attached below for an example:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Lubuntu 23.04 so that I get the windows grouped again as in Lubuntu 22.04?
Thank you all for this help!
Cheers.

PS: LXQt version on Lubuntu 22.04 was: 0.14.1 Qt: 5.12.8 The actual LXQt version is: 1.2.0 Qt: 5.15.8

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't?   I've not noticed any difference, and have multiple panels with the grouping on one panel (*as I want*) but **not** on the other panel.   It operates identically to 22.04 (*though you didn't state which version of LXQt you were using on 22.04; ie. the original version or one upgraded using backports*).  https://linux-tips.us/disable-window-grouping-in-lubuntu/ maybe useful

Comment: Hey guiverc,
Thanks for you insight.
The LXQt version on Lubuntu 22.04 was: 0.14.1
Qt: 5.12.8
The actual LXQt version is: 1.2.0
Qt: 5.15.8
In the print screen of my panel I've attached, there are 2 windows of Firefox, 2 of libreoffice write and 4 of Okular pdf viewer opened and 8 tabs (not 3 groups as I wanted).

Comment: guiverc: thank you very much for the link you provided me with. I followed the steps as I wanted to disable window grouping and the checkbox "window grouping" was already unchecked (probably default on this new version as it appears the majority of people doesn't like window grouping... kkkk). So I ticked it and solved the issue! Thank you once again.

Comment: FYI:  Yes the LXQt in 22.04 was 0.14.1 by default; but could be upgraded to 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2 via Lubuntu *backports* (https://lubuntu.me/category/release/backports/) which is why I asked about LXQt verison... ie. 22.04 using *backports* & fully upgraded uses the same LXQt version found in 23..04

Comment: Thank you guiverc!

Comment: ps:  I've pinged @KGIII who is the author of the blog I provided (Linux Tips) and also a Lubuntu member to write an answer (*if he wants & is able to*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question. I dislike window grouping and wrote the referenced article (in the comments) about how you [disable window grouping](https://linux-tips.us/disable-window-grouping-in-lubuntu/).

As you are one of the people who like the feature, this is easily changed. You just reverse what's in the article, meaning you add the checkmark to enable the feature.

1. Right-click on an empty space on the panel and click on Configure Panel.
2. Click on Widgets (on the left) and then Task Manager.
3. Find the "Window Grouping" option and add the checkmark.
4. Click on "Close" (and not on "Reset")

The image should help make this more clear:

[image: Enable Window Grouping in Lubuntu/LXQt]

That's really all you need to do.

Comment: You may have misread the question. The user *likes* window grouping and want to enable it. Still, your answer may help the user to find the setting.

Comment: @vanadium Ha! That's exactly what I did. I was in a rush and someone pinged me to this question as they knew about the article. I'll fix it up. (And done.)

Comment: Hello KGIII! 
Thank you very much for your answer!
I've already done the steps you showed when reading your article posted by guiverc.
I know Lubuntu is very customizable but this time I couldn't figure out where to configure this.
I hope others like me and you could be helped by this question and your article.
Thank you again folks!
Have a nice one!

Comment: @RafaelEliasGrigolo Please accept this answer if you're happy with it; the question is still marked as UNSOLVED as no answer has been accepted (the word 'solved' in the title means nothing on this site).

Comment: @guiverc Done! Thank you once again.